# IIS doesn't show my web page

Tags: asp.net, iis

I had some problems to show my webPage using IIS 8.0.
Now I get no erros when I open my page through `IIS` but now it only appears:

---

Local host - /
Date Time Folder's Name
Date Time Folder's Name
Date Time Folder's Name

What Should I do to show my WebPage?
I already `checked` the `ASP.NET` option on `Active or Desactive Windows Features`of `control panel`.

Comment: Do you have a page to show? From the example above, it does not look like it

Comment: Got an index.html to show? Its one of the defaults it looks for.

Comment: I'm a ´noob` working with `WEB. Let me tell you, I have an almost complete system, i'm using it on Visual Studio and it's working fine. I just don't know how to use it throught IIS. because My Boss want to try the web site...

Comment: @VenomFangs I have my pages.apsx, the first page that opens when I debug my solution on VS, isnt the same for IIS ? Please help me !

Comment: @Ghaleon, sounds like you are new to IIS. If would recommend doing some googling and watching some tutorial videos, even if of earlier versions, so you get an idea of the setup/configuration you'll need to do. E.g. The following is a tutorial on IIS7: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBNoTK31zPo

Comment: @VenomFangs Thanks man ! I really appretiace that, but I really need to put this online (intranet), or my boss will kill me ;s
Could you tell me just how to set the default page ? i'll watch it right now

Comment: @Ghaleon, look at my answer. I gave you a basic page to try to display and then its just a matter of setting the webpage up properly. I apologize, I thought you were trying to actually setup a website with your stuff, not just display it locally. Anyway, a couple googles and you should find what you are looking for. If you can't find what you need with IIS8 googles, use IIS7 and you should be able to bridge the gaps.

Comment: @VenomFangs could not download 7. Actually I WANT 7.. because its the version that is installed on our server... When I downloaded my currently `IIS` it was `v8.0` but now I saw it is the `v7.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a custom page name for your default page like "mypages.aspx" as in your case, you can configure to do so in your `web.config`

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
        <files>
            <add value="~/mypages.aspx"/>
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

You can do the same in IIS going to `DefaultDocument` section under your deployed site settings in IIS. Check [this](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument) and [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899450/iis8-default-document-yields-404-not-found-error) as your are using IIS8 for more info.

Comment: I'll try, but tell me, now that I need to change the content of my `web.config`, do I need to delete my currently website on IIS and do everything again or is there a simpler way ?

Comment: No you don't need to delete anything. If you are publishing to the IIS from within visualstudio then Just change add the config to the existing `web.config` of your project. If you are deploying it manually, then replace the `web.config` file in `Inetpub/../your site directory/web.config` on your IIS machine.

Comment: That's what I don't get ...I don't know the right steps to publish it , I guess that's what I did wrong I dont know... =s

Comment: In your question you said you see local host with folders etc. Navigate and see if you find your `my pages.aspx` and click on it. If its opening then you deployed it correctly. Also check [this video](http://pluralsight.com/training/players/PSODPlayer?author=fritz-onion&name=webforms-09&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-webforms4-intro) series on how to deploy to IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to make sure you have a default webpage? E.g. index.html, index.asp, default.html or default.asp? The names are based on the settings of the site of course.

Make a basic html page:

```
<html>
<body>
Hello world.
</body>
</html>
```

Then put it in the directory IIS is looking for, for the website. You'll want to make sure you setup your DNS to reflect the domain you are trying to host, and then change your local network settings to use your computer's IP before any other DNS. This will allow you to see the website.

Comment: I think so, isn't it the same that opens when I debug the solution on Visual Studio ? Well, I don't have any with these names... IN VS, my first page is the log in page.

Comment: @Ghaleon, gave you some more info. You'll want the default page. If you are actually trying to setup the webpage with a domain name. You'll need to setup the DNS and then have your server look at itself for the DNS before any other DNS.

Comment: What is the directory that ISS is looking for ? I putted it on `wwwroot` but didn't work out ;s

Comment: I created a folder and inside this folder I putted the txt you told me to create. Then I putted this folder inside `wwwroot` Then `I converted the folder to Application`, then RUN and got this error:
http://i50.tinypic.com/b3rcxk.png