# Added new website to IIS8 and still goes to Default Website

Tags: iis, web, windows-server-2012, iis-8, windows-server

Setting up a new server - 2012 with IIS8. I added a new web site to IIS8. I set the IP address and the hostname.

Yet when I browse to the site, it goes to the Default Website instead. I stopped the Default web site and I get a 404. I tried restarting IIS as well.

I read a few pages on how to set up a new website and I seem to be in compliance. The Default Website is just a fallback as I understand it. With the hostname and/or the IP address set, IIS should direct traffic to the new web site, right?

I made sure the folder had permissions for the app pool (though the Test Settings is still failing the Authorization Test.) and the IUSR. I temporarily used the Administrator account instead of pass-thtough so I could pass the Authorization Test.

I enabled ASP.Net impersonation.

I verified default document file name. I tried a simple .html to get around any ASP.net issues.

I deleted it and started from scratch, using the DefaultAppPool this time.

What am I missing here?

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: Ok...how many IP addresses does your server have, what IP address is assigned to the default website and what IP address are you trying to use on your new site?

Comment: One IP address on the server. No IP address or host is assigned to the the default default web site - it is stock.

Comment: I found a solution on another thread. I added my specifics to broaden the scope of the solution. Link here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899450/iis8-default-document-yields-404-not-found-error/)