# ColdFusion only serves default document

Tags: iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

In IIS, I have the following listed as default documents

[image]

`index.cfm` exists and is shown if I navigate to the root of the site.

As soon as I try `https://localhost:1234/index.cfm`, I get 404.0 error

Comment: How is everything set up? Did wsconfig run successfully? Is the port 1234 right? Is the right path configured?

Comment: Same port before and after.

Comment: Try rerunning the WSConfig utility on the site.

Comment: And this is why I don't contribute to SO that much.  Legit question, legit answers: all negative ratings.

Comment: Someday someone will have a similar issue. They will search for it and they will find this answer. The down votes may make it harder find, but when they find it, it will change their day and make it better. I could delete my question, but then that person would not be helped.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is the solution that fixed the issue.

If one goes to IIS, there is a virtual directory `/jakarta`

The physical path associated with the virtual directory was `ColdFusion2016\config\wsconfig\1`

[image]

By adding the `D:` drive, all works OK.

Comment: You should use the WSConfig tool to manage the /jakarta virtual directory.  If it's not setting the path correctly something is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

You can resolve this error by making sure that the two required components of IIS are installed on your system. Namely:

1. ISAPI Extensions
2. IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility.

First, start the program called Windows Features. You will find Windows Features under Control Panel –> Programs and Features.

[image]

When the Windows Features starts, navigate through the features hierarchy under Internet Information Services and select the two features: ISAPI extensions and IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility.

[image]

[image]

ColdFusion is now ready to run from IIS. However, IF you’ve ALREADY installed ColdFusion before following the above steps, continue to follow the steps mentioned under ‘Configuring IIS for ColdFusion’:

**Configuring IIS for ColdFusion**

If you followed the above steps after having installed ColdFusion 8 or 9, you will have to run Web Server Configuration Tool that comes with ColdFusion to configure IIS7 so that all .CFM files are mapped to be handled by ColdFusion.

The following text is directly from ColdFusion installation guide:

1.Start the Web Server Configuration Tool by selecting Start > Programs > Adobe > ColdFusion 9 > Web Server Configuration Tool.

2. Click Add.
3. In the Server pop-up menu, select the host name and the server or cluster name to configure. In the ColdFusion server configuration, the server name is always coldfusion. Clustering support is not available on the server configuration.
4. In the Web Server Properties area, select IIS and specify the website. For IIS, you typically specify All.
5. Select the Configure web server for ColdFusion applications option, and click OK.
6. Copy the CFIDE and cfdocs directories from cf_root/wwwroot to your web server root directory. In addition, copy your application’s CFM pages from cf_root/wwwroot to your web server root directory. In the multiserver configuration, these files are under the jrun_root/servers/cfusion/cfusion-ear/cfusion-war directory.

ColdFusion is now ready to serve pages on the Web;

***The above content comes from a [blog](https://forums.iis.net/t/1005992.aspx?ColdFusion%20does%20not%20know%20how%20to%20setup%20IIS%207).***

Comment: That blog post is specifically for connecting older versions (8/9) of ACF that ran on JRun with IIS7. The OP is using ACF 2016, which runs on Tomcat, and should be on IIS 10.

Comment: I can serve a single web page, the default document. I just can't get anything else. I also can't see the default page if I specify its name.

Answer (score -2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12910827/11047) mentions an issue where IIS 8 only responded to the last default document in the list of default documents. Are you using IIS 10 with ACF 2016?

If you are getting this response now:

- https://localhost:1234/index.cfm 404.0
- https://localhost:1234/default.cfm 200

What does this return? Only `default.cfm`?

- https://localhost:1234/

Remove the entry for `default.cfm` and restart IIS. Does that respond to `index.cfm`? If you're not going to use that file as a default anyway, no need to define it as such.

Can you post your `web.config` file for that site, just the relevant portion, to confirm the values? Could it be showing the global default in the UI, but not actually inheriting that for the specific site?

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
        <files>
            <add value="index.cfm" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is the exact opposite of my problem. I can see the default document, but I can't see anything else. I can't the default document if I specify its name either.