# When debugging web service in Visual Studio, Directory Listing --/ is shown instead of default page

Tags: web-services, wcf

[image]

[image]

I tried to debug with "Local IIS"

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name of the page in the part of IIS where you deploy site Settings. Also check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/defaultDocument/) and [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899450/iis8-default-document-yields-404-not-found-error) for more.